# Predictive text conversion from vanilla js to react js component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a vanilla js attempt at doing a predictive text output - where the user would type -- "order my plasters to home from wimple pharmacy"

How do I convert this vanilla js into a react component -I've taken the current core functions in predictiveSearch and placed them inside the same scope of the react component, but the way he had made the predictive lists and the dom handling is different.

```js
class predictiveSearch {
    initialize() {
        // Elements of the HTML page
        this.text_input = document.getElementById('SearchBox')
        this.hints = document.getElementById('predictions')
        this._1st_hint =  document.getElementById('first_prediction')


        // The data to be used for prediction
        // "to" -> if it full matches then it will show the suggestions of its sub-objects
        //      -> selecting home will add a space and make it "...to home"
        this.predict_assets = {
            to: [{
                    key: 'home',
                    details: '20 Glenbrook Dr, Hillsborough CA 92591',
                },
                {
                    key: 'work',
                    details: '400 S El Camino Real San Mateo, CA 92591',
                },
            ],
            from: [{
                    key: 'Wimpole Pharmacy',
                    details: 'pharmacies',
                },
                {
                    key: 'JP Pharmacy',
                    details: 'pharmacies',
                },
                {
                    key: 'Morrisons Pharmacy',
                    details: 'pharmacies',
                },
            ],
        }

        this.predict_assets_keys = Object.keys(this.predict_assets)
        this.KeywordRegex = new RegExp(
            `(^|\\s)(${this.predict_assets_keys.join('|')})`,
            'gi',
        )
    }

    /**
     * Creates a hint element with the given match, text, details, input element, regex, and new text.
     * @param {string} match - The matched text. (ignored because click disabled)
     * @param {string} text - The original text. (ignored because click disabled)
     * @param {string} details - The details to display in the hint.
     * @param {HTMLElement} input_ele - The input element to attach the hint to. (ignored because click disabled)
     * @param {RegExp} regex - The regular expression used to match the text. (ignored because click disabled)
     * @param {string} new_text - The new text to display in the hint.
     * @returns {HTMLElement} The hint element.
     */
    make_hint(match, text, details, input_ele, regex, new_text) {
        const that = this;

        const li = document.createElement('div')
        li.className = 'hint'
        li.innerHTML = `<b>${new_text}</b> <br> <i>${details}<i>`

        return li
    }

    /**
     * Generates a regular expression pattern for a given string. It matches characters one by one.
     * @param {string} str - The input string to generate the pattern for.
     * @param {boolean} [end=false] - Whether to include an end-of-line anchor in the pattern.
     * @returns {string} The regular expression pattern for the input string.
     */
    make_regex(str, end=false) {
        let i = str.length;
        var prev_ptrn = '';
        while (i--) {
            const char = str.charAt(i);
            prev_ptrn = (`(${char}${prev_ptrn})?`);
        }

        // drop the last ?
        prev_ptrn = prev_ptrn.slice(0, -1)

        if (end) return `(?<res2>${prev_ptrn})\$`
        return `(?<res2>${prev_ptrn})`
    }

    
    /**
     * Replaces the matched substring in the given text with the specified replacement text.
     * @param {string} text - The input text to be modified.
     * @param {RegExp} regex - The regular expression pattern to match against the input text.
     * @param {string} text2 - The replacement text to be used in place of the matched substring.
     * @returns {string} The modified text with the matched substring replaced by the replacement text.
     */
    swap_text(text, regex, text2) {
        return text.replace(regex, text2)
    }


    
    /**
     * Updates the first hint text with the given input and new text.
     * @param {string} input - The input text.
     * @param {string} new_text - The new text to be added to the hint.
     */
    update_1st_hint_text(input, new_text){
        const _1st_hint = this._1st_hint

        
        // Get the new suggestion text by splitting the new text by the original keyword.
        const new_part = new_text.slice(input.length, new_text.length)

        const span = document.createElement('pre')
        span.className = 'text_hint'
        span.innerHTML = new_part
        // show the new suggestion text in different color


        // show the full suggestion text
        _1st_hint.innerHTML = ''
        _1st_hint.innerText = input // 1st show the input text      
        _1st_hint.appendChild(span) // then show the new suggestion text

    }

    update() {
        const that = this;

        const text_input = this.text_input
        const value = text_input.value
        this.hints.innerHTML = ''
        this._1st_hint.innerHTML = ''



        var prediction_made = false;

        if (value.length > 0) {
            const matches = value.match(this.KeywordRegex)
            // checks if the input text contains any of the keywords like "to", "from", etc.

            if (!matches) return;

            for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                const key = matches[i].trim().toLowerCase()

                // get the next predictions for the keyword
                const predictions = that.predict_assets[key]
                // if the user has written something after the keyword, then show matching with the keyword
                predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
                    // make a regex pattern for the keyword to check characters one by one. If rest of part missing then also match. But if typo or mismatch won't work.
                    var option = that.make_regex(prediction.key, false)

                    // search by the main keyword and the prediction key
                    var regex = new RegExp(`(?<space>^|\\s)${key}\\s?(${option}?$)`, 'gi')
                    const match2 = regex.exec(value)

                    if (match2) {
                        // if theres space before the keyword then add space in the final text
                        const t = `${match2.groups.space}${key} ${prediction.key}`

                        // make a hint element
                        const li = that.make_hint(key, prediction.key, prediction.details, text_input, regex, t)
                        this.hints.appendChild(li)

                        if (!prediction_made) {
                            const new_text = that.swap_text(value, regex, t)

                            // update the first hint text (with different color suggestion)
                            that.update_1st_hint_text(value, new_text)
                            prediction_made = true
                        }
                    }
                })
            }


        }
    }


    predict() {
        const that = this;

        this.text_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            that.update()
        })
    }


}

const predictive_search = new predictiveSearch()
predictive_search.predict()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Predictive search</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="searchBar">
        <input type="text" name="SearchBox" id="SearchBox" placeholder="Enter your query">
        <p id="first_prediction"></p>
        <div id="predictions"></div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

the current react conversion looks like this -- I need to add more refs and swap out the getelementids

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-ganguly-23phc8?file=/src/_globals/PredictiveText/PredictiveText.js

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser'
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid'

import GeneralFormik from '../GeneralFormik/GeneralFormik'

import PlaceIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Place'

import './PredictiveText.scss'

class PredictiveText extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      suggestions: [],
      transcriptLength: 0,
      transcript: '',
      highlightedText: '',

      data: {
        to: [
          {
            key: 'home',
            details: '20 Glenbrook Dr, Hillsborough CA 92591',
          },
          {
            key: 'work',
            details: '400 S El Camino Real San Mateo, CA 92591',
          },
        ],
        from: [
          {
            key: 'Wimpole Pharmacy',
            details: 'pharmacies',
          },
          {
            key: 'JP Pharmacy',
            details: 'pharmacies',
          },
          {
            key: 'Morrisons Pharmacy',
            details: 'pharmacies',
          },
        ],
        a: [
          {
            key: 'schedule',
            details: 'callback',
          },
          {
            key: 'schedule',
            details: 'video conference',
          },
          {
            key: 'schedule',
            details: 'chat',
          },
        ],
      },
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    this.myRef = React.createRef()
  }

  getSchema() {
    let schema = {
      initialValues: {
        command: '',
      },
      fields: [
        {
          type: 'text',
          name: 'command',
          label: '',
          //"validation": yup.string('Enter your email').required("email is required"),
          //"disabled": true
        },
      ],
      buttons: [],
    }

    return schema
  }

  handleChange(data) {
    let transcript = data.command

    this.myRef.current.innerHTML = transcript
  }

  initialize() {
    // Elements of the HTML page
    this.text_input = document.getElementById('SearchBox')
    this.hints = document.getElementById('predictions')
    this._1st_hint = document.getElementById('first_prediction')

    // The data to be used for prediction
    // "to" -> if it full matches then it will show the suggestions of its sub-objects
    //      -> selecting home will add a space and make it "...to home"
    this.predict_assets = {
      to: [
        {
          key: 'home',
          details: '20 Glenbrook Dr, Hillsborough CA 92591',
        },
        {
          key: 'work',
          details: '400 S El Camino Real San Mateo, CA 92591',
        },
      ],
      from: [
        {
          key: 'Wimpole Pharmacy',
          details: 'pharmacies',
        },
        {
          key: 'JP Pharmacy',
          details: 'pharmacies',
        },
        {
          key: 'Morrisons Pharmacy',
          details: 'pharmacies',
        },
      ],
    }

    this.predict_assets_keys = Object.keys(this.predict_assets)
    this.KeywordRegex = new RegExp(
      `(^|\\s)(${this.predict_assets_keys.join('|')})`,
      'gi',
    )
  }

  /**
   * Creates a hint element with the given match, text, details, input element, regex, and new text.
   * @param {string} match - The matched text. (ignored because click disabled)
   * @param {string} text - The original text. (ignored because click disabled)
   * @param {string} details - The details to display in the hint.
   * @param {HTMLElement} input_ele - The input element to attach the hint to. (ignored because click disabled)
   * @param {RegExp} regex - The regular expression used to match the text. (ignored because click disabled)
   * @param {string} new_text - The new text to display in the hint.
   * @returns {HTMLElement} The hint element.
   */
  make_hint(match, text, details, input_ele, regex, new_text) {
    const that = this

    const li = document.createElement('div')
    li.className = 'hint'
    li.innerHTML = `<b>${new_text}</b> <br> <i>${details}<i>`

    return li
  }

  /**
   * Generates a regular expression pattern for a given string. It matches characters one by one.
   * @param {string} str - The input string to generate the pattern for.
   * @param {boolean} [end=false] - Whether to include an end-of-line anchor in the pattern.
   * @returns {string} The regular expression pattern for the input string.
   */
  make_regex(str, end = false) {
    let i = str.length
    var prev_ptrn = ''
    while (i--) {
      const char = str.charAt(i)
      prev_ptrn = `(${char}${prev_ptrn})?`
    }

    // drop the last ?
    prev_ptrn = prev_ptrn.slice(0, -1)

    if (end) return `(?<res2>${prev_ptrn})\$`
    return `(?<res2>${prev_ptrn})`
  }

  /**
   * Replaces the matched substring in the given text with the specified replacement text.
   * @param {string} text - The input text to be modified.
   * @param {RegExp} regex - The regular expression pattern to match against the input text.
   * @param {string} text2 - The replacement text to be used in place of the matched substring.
   * @returns {string} The modified text with the matched substring replaced by the replacement text.
   */
  swap_text(text, regex, text2) {
    return text.replace(regex, text2)
  }

  /**
   * Updates the first hint text with the given input and new text.
   * @param {string} input - The input text.
   * @param {string} new_text - The new text to be added to the hint.
   */
  update_1st_hint_text(input, new_text) {
    const _1st_hint = this._1st_hint

    // Get the new suggestion text by splitting the new text by the original keyword.
    const new_part = new_text.slice(input.length, new_text.length)

    const span = document.createElement('pre')
    span.className = 'text_hint'
    span.innerHTML = new_part
    // show the new suggestion text in different color

    // show the full suggestion text
    _1st_hint.innerHTML = ''
    _1st_hint.innerText = input // 1st show the input text
    _1st_hint.appendChild(span) // then show the new suggestion text
  }

  update() {
    const that = this

    const text_input = this.text_input
    const value = text_input.value
    this.hints.innerHTML = ''
    this._1st_hint.innerHTML = ''

    var prediction_made = false

    if (value.length > 0) {
      const matches = value.match(this.KeywordRegex)
      // checks if the input text contains any of the keywords like "to", "from", etc.

      if (!matches) return

      for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        const key = matches[i].trim().toLowerCase()

        // get the next predictions for the keyword
        const predictions = that.predict_assets[key]
        // if the user has written something after the keyword, then show matching with the keyword
        predictions.forEach((prediction) => {
          // make a regex pattern for the keyword to check characters one by one. If rest of part missing then also match. But if typo or mismatch won't work.
          var option = that.make_regex(prediction.key, false)

          // search by the main keyword and the prediction key
          var regex = new RegExp(`(?<space>^|\\s)${key}\\s?(${option}?$)`, 'gi')
          const match2 = regex.exec(value)

          if (match2) {
            // if theres space before the keyword then add space in the final text
            const t = `${match2.groups.space}${key} ${prediction.key}`

            // make a hint element
            const li = that.make_hint(
              key,
              prediction.key,
              prediction.details,
              text_input,
              regex,
              t,
            )
            this.hints.appendChild(li)

            if (!prediction_made) {
              const new_text = that.swap_text(value, regex, t)

              // update the first hint text (with different color suggestion)
              that.update_1st_hint_text(value, new_text)
              prediction_made = true
            }
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }

  predict() {
    const that = this

    this.text_input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
      that.update()
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="PredictiveText">
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
            <div className="predictive-text">
              <GeneralFormik
                schema={this.getSchema()}
                submitHandler={this.handleChange}
              />
              <div className="parent-element">
                <div ref={this.myRef}></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PredictiveText
```